# error creating Opengl 3.3 Context under ubuntu 14.10 64 bits

Tags: opengl, x11

i need some help to make run this code in Ubuntu 14.10 64 bits. I compiled this code in ubuntu 14.04 32 bits and worked fine... but if i translate this into 14.10 in 64 bits (same PC, another partition),i can't create an Opengl 3.3 context. I dont know what the problem is.

here is mi code glxwindow.h

```
#ifndef GLXWINDOW_H_INCLUDED
#define GLXWINDOW_H_INCLUDED

#ifndef WIN32

#include "oslibraries.h"
#include <ctime>

#include "boglgpwindow.h"

namespace SGE3D
{
    class core; //Declara la clase principal del juego
}

namespace SGE3D
{

class SimpleGLXWindow : public BOGLGPWindow
{
public:
    SimpleGLXWindow(); //default constructor
    virtual ~SimpleGLXWindow();

    bool create(int width, int height, int bpp, bool fullscreen);
    void destroy();
    void processEvents();
    void attachExample(SGE3D::core* example);
    void setWindowTitle(char* wName);

    bool isRunning(); //Is the window running?

    void swapBuffers();

    float getElapsedSeconds();

    KeyboardInterface* getKeyboard() const { return m_keyboard; }
    MouseInterface* getMouse() const { return m_mouse; }
    void resizeOpenGLViewPortFull(float wRight, float wLeft);
    void resizeOpenGLViewPort(float x, float y, float wRight, float wLeft);
    int getViewPortWidth();
    int getViewPortHeight();
    int getWindowWidth();
    int getWindowHeight();
private:
    SGE3D::core* m_example; //manejador de la clase principal del juego
    bool m_isRunning; //Is the window still running?
    char* m_windowTitle;

    SGE3D::core* getAttachedExample() { return m_example; }

    unsigned int m_lastTime;

    Display* m_display;
    Window m_XWindow;
    GLXContext m_glContext;
    XF86VidModeModeInfo m_XF86DeskMode;
    XSetWindowAttributes m_XSetAttr;
    //agregado
    XWindowAttributes m_gwa;
    int m_screenID;

    bool m_isFullscreen;
    unsigned int m_width;
    unsigned int m_height;
    unsigned int m_bpp;

    bool m_GL3Supported;

    SGE3D::KeyboardInterface* m_keyboard;//manejador del teclado
    SGE3D::MouseInterface* m_mouse;//manejador del mouse

    //viewPort
    int viewPortWidth,viewPortHeight;
    int windowWidth,windowHeight;

    //cierra la ventana
    Atom WM_DELETE_WINDOW;
};
}
#endif //WIN32
#endif // GLXWINDOW_H_INCLUDED
```

this is the glxwindow.cpp

```
#ifndef WIN32

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <sys/time.h>

#include "opengl.h"
#include "glxwindow.h"
#include "core.h"
#include "xkeyboardinterface.h"
#include "xmouseinterface.h"

//SOLO DEBUG
#include "sysconfiguration.h"
#include "pcreport.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using std::cout;

using std::string;

typedef GLXContext (*glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)(Display*, GLXFBConfig, GLXContext, Bool, const int*);

static bool isExtensionSupported(const char *extList, const char *extension)
{
  const char *start;
  const char *where, *terminator;

  /* Extension names should not have spaces. */
  where = strchr(extension, ' ');
  if (where || *extension == '\0')
    return false;

  /* It takes a bit of care to be fool-proof about parsing the
     OpenGL extensions string. Don't be fooled by sub-strings,
     etc. */
  for (start=extList;;) {
    where = strstr(start, extension);

    if (!where)
      break;

    terminator = where + strlen(extension);

    if ( where == start || *(where - 1) == ' ' )
      if ( *terminator == ' ' || *terminator == '\0' )
        return true;

    start = terminator;
  }

  return false;
}

unsigned int GetTickCount() {
    struct timeval t;
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);

    unsigned long secs = t.tv_sec * 1000;
    secs += (t.tv_usec / 1000);
    return secs;
}

static bool ctxErrorOccurred = false;
static int ctxErrorHandler( Display *dpy, XErrorEvent *ev )
{
    ctxErrorOccurred = true;
    return 0;
}

namespace SGE3D
{

SimpleGLXWindow::SimpleGLXWindow():
m_example(NULL),
m_windowTitle("Skalium Graphic Engine 3D"),
m_isRunning(true),
m_lastTime(0),
m_display(NULL),
m_XWindow(0),
m_glContext(0),
m_screenID(0),
m_isFullscreen(false),
m_width(0),
m_height(0),
m_bpp(0),
m_GL3Supported(false),
m_keyboard(NULL),
m_mouse(NULL)
{
    m_keyboard = new XKeyboardInterface();//instancia el teclado
}

SimpleGLXWindow::~SimpleGLXWindow()
{
    delete m_keyboard;
    delete m_mouse;
}

void SimpleGLXWindow::resizeOpenGLViewPortFull(float wRight, float wLeft)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, wRight, wLeft);
    viewPortWidth = wRight;
    viewPortHeight = wLeft;
}

void SimpleGLXWindow::resizeOpenGLViewPort(float x, float y, float wRight, float wLeft)
{
    glViewport(x, y, wRight, wLeft);
    viewPortWidth = wRight;
    viewPortHeight = wLeft;
}

int SimpleGLXWindow::getViewPortWidth()
{
    return viewPortWidth;
}

int SimpleGLXWindow::getViewPortHeight()
{
    return viewPortHeight;
}

int SimpleGLXWindow::getWindowWidth()
{
    return windowWidth;
}

int SimpleGLXWindow::getWindowHeight()
{
    return windowHeight;
}

bool SimpleGLXWindow::create(int width, int height, int bpp, bool fullscreen)
{
    windowWidth = width;
    windowHeight = height;
    m_isFullscreen = fullscreen; //guarda el flag "fullscreen"

    m_display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);  //Open default display

    if (m_display == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "No se pudo abrir el display." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }


    int doubleBufferedAttribList [] = {
      GLX_X_RENDERABLE    , True,
      GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE   , GLX_WINDOW_BIT,
      GLX_RENDER_TYPE     , GLX_RGBA_BIT,
      GLX_X_VISUAL_TYPE   , GLX_TRUE_COLOR,
      GLX_RED_SIZE        , 8,
      GLX_GREEN_SIZE      , 8,
      GLX_BLUE_SIZE       , 8,
      GLX_ALPHA_SIZE      , 8,
      GLX_DEPTH_SIZE      , 24,
      GLX_STENCIL_SIZE    , 8,
      GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER    , True,
      GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS  , 1,
      GLX_SAMPLES         , 4,
      None
    };


    int glx_major, glx_minor;

    // FBConfigs were added in GLX version 1.3.
    if ( !glXQueryVersion( m_display, &glx_major, &glx_minor ) || ( ( glx_major == 1 ) && ( glx_minor < 3 ) ) || ( glx_major < 1 ) )
    {
        cout << "Invalid GLX version\n";
        return false;
    }

//    XVisualInfo* vi = NULL;
    //Attempt to create a double buffered window
    int fbcount;
//    vi = glXChooseVisual(m_display, m_screenID, doubleBufferedAttribList,&fbcount);
    GLXFBConfig* fbc = glXChooseFBConfig(m_display, DefaultScreen(m_display), doubleBufferedAttribList,&fbcount);

    if (!fbc)
  {
    cout <<"Failed to retrieve a framebuffer config\n";
return false;
  }
  cout << "Found "<< fbcount<< " matching FB configs.\n";

  // Pick the FB config/visual with the most samples per pixel
 cout << "Getting XVisualInfos\n";
  int best_fbc = -1, worst_fbc = -1, best_num_samp = -1, worst_num_samp = 999;

  int i;
  for (i=0; i<fbcount; ++i)
  {
    XVisualInfo *vi = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig( m_display, fbc[i] );
    if ( vi )
    {
      int samp_buf, samples;
      glXGetFBConfigAttrib( m_display, fbc[i], GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, &samp_buf );
      glXGetFBConfigAttrib( m_display, fbc[i], GLX_SAMPLES       , &samples  );

      cout << "Matching fbconfig " << i <<", visual ID "<< vi -> visualid <<": SAMPLE_BUFFERS = " << samp_buf << ", SAMPLES = "<< samples << "\n";

      if ( best_fbc < 0 || samp_buf && samples > best_num_samp )
        best_fbc = i, best_num_samp = samples;
      if ( worst_fbc < 0 || !samp_buf || samples < worst_num_samp )
        worst_fbc = i, worst_num_samp = samples;
    }
    XFree( vi );
  }

  GLXFBConfig bestFbc = fbc[ best_fbc ];

  // Be sure to free the FBConfig list allocated by glXChooseFBConfig()
  XFree( fbc );

  // Get a visual
  XVisualInfo *vi = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig( m_display, bestFbc );
  cout << "Chosen visual ID = " << vi->visualid << "\n";

  cout << "Creating colormap\n";
  XSetWindowAttributes swa;
  Colormap cmap;
  swa.colormap = cmap = XCreateColormap( m_display,
                                         RootWindow( m_display, vi->screen ),
                                         vi->visual, AllocNone );
  swa.background_pixmap = None ;
  swa.border_pixel      = 0;
  swa.event_mask        = ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | ButtonPress |
                          StructureNotifyMask | ButtonReleaseMask |
                          KeyReleaseMask | EnterWindowMask | LeaveWindowMask |
                          PointerMotionMask | Button1MotionMask | VisibilityChangeMask |
                          ColormapChangeMask;

  cout << "Creating window\n";
  m_XWindow = XCreateWindow( m_display, RootWindow( m_display, vi->screen ),
                              0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, vi->depth, InputOutput,
                              vi->visual,
                              CWBorderPixel | CWColormap | CWEventMask | CWOverrideRedirect | CWCursor, &swa );
  if ( !m_XWindow )
  {
    cout << "Failed to create window.\n";
    return false;
  }

  // Done with the visual info data
  XFree( vi );

  XStoreName( m_display, m_XWindow, m_windowTitle );

  cout <<"Mapping window\n";
  XMapWindow( m_display, m_XWindow );

  // Get the default screen's GLX extension list
  const char *glxExts = glXQueryExtensionsString( m_display,
                                                  DefaultScreen( m_display ) );

  // NOTE: It is not necessary to create or make current to a context before
  // calling glXGetProcAddressARB
  glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc glXCreateContextAttribsARB = 0;
  glXCreateContextAttribsARB = (glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)
           glXGetProcAddressARB( (const GLubyte *) "glXCreateContextAttribsARB" );

  GLXContext ctx = 0;

  // Install an X error handler so the application won't exit if GL 3.0
  // context allocation fails.
  //
  // Note this error handler is global.  All display connections in all threads
  // of a process use the same error handler, so be sure to guard against other
  // threads issuing X commands while this code is running.
  ctxErrorOccurred = false;
  int (*oldHandler)(Display*, XErrorEvent*) =
      XSetErrorHandler(&ctxErrorHandler);

  // Check for the GLX_ARB_create_context extension string and the function.
  // If either is not present, use GLX 1.3 context creation method.
  if ( !isExtensionSupported( glxExts, "GLX_ARB_create_context" ) ||
       !glXCreateContextAttribsARB )
  {
    printf( "glXCreateContextAttribsARB() not found"
            " ... using old-style GLX context\n" );
    ctx = glXCreateNewContext( m_display, bestFbc, GLX_RGBA_TYPE, 0, True );
  }

   //If it does, try to get a GL 3.0 context!
  else
  {
    int context_attribs[] =
      {
        GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB , GLX_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        //GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB        , GLX_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
        None
      };

    cout << "Creating context\n";
    ctx = glXCreateContextAttribsARB( m_display, bestFbc, 0,
                                      True, context_attribs );

    // Sync to ensure any errors generated are processed.
    XSync( m_display, False );
    if ( !ctxErrorOccurred && ctx )
      cout << "Created GL 3.0 context\n";
    else
    {
      // Couldn't create GL 3.0 context.  Fall back to old-style 2.x context.
      // When a context version below 3.0 is requested, implementations will
      // return the newest context version compatible with OpenGL versions less
      // than version 3.0.
      // GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB = 1
      context_attribs[1] = 1;
      // GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB = 0
      context_attribs[3] = 0;

      ctxErrorOccurred = false;

      cout << "Failed to create GL 3.3 context ... using old-style GLX context\n";
      ctx = glXCreateContextAttribsARB( m_display, bestFbc, 0,
                                        True, context_attribs );
    }
  }

  // Sync to ensure any errors generated are processed.
  XSync( m_display, False );

  // Restore the original error handler
  XSetErrorHandler( oldHandler );

  if ( ctxErrorOccurred || !ctx )
  {
    cout <<"Failed to create an OpenGL context\n";
    return false;
  }

  // Verifying that context is a direct context
  if ( ! glXIsDirect ( m_display, ctx ) )
  {
    cout << "Indirect GLX rendering context obtained\n";
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Direct GLX rendering context obtained\n";
  }

  cout <<"Making context current\n" ;
  glXMakeCurrent( m_display, m_XWindow, ctx );

  m_GL3Supported = true;

    //para correcto cerrado de la ventana
    WM_DELETE_WINDOW = XInternAtom(m_display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
    XSetWMProtocols(m_display, m_XWindow, &WM_DELETE_WINDOW, 1);

    m_mouse = new XMouseInterface(&m_XWindow);
    m_mouse->showCursor(true);
//    //Make the new context current
//    glXMakeCurrent(m_display, m_XWindow, m_glContext);
////
////    int posx = 0;
////    int posy = 0;
////    Window winDummy;
//    unsigned int borderDummy;
//
    m_width = (unsigned) width;
    m_height = (unsigned) height;
//    m_bpp = (unsigned) bpp;
//
//    XGetGeometry(m_display, m_XWindow, &winDummy,
//                 &posx, &posy, &m_width, &m_height,
//                 &borderDummy, &m_bpp);

    m_lastTime = GetTickCount(); //Initialize the time

    if(m_GL3Supported)
    {
        cout << "inicializando glew...\n";
        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        //inicializando glew
        GLenum error = glewInit(); // Enable GLEW
        if (error != GLEW_OK) // If GLEW fails
        {
            cout << "Error al iniciar la librería GLEW: " << glewGetErrorString(error) << ".\nNo es posible continuar con la ejecución de Skalium Graphic Engine 3D.";
            return false;
        }
    }

    return m_GL3Supported;
}

void SimpleGLXWindow::destroy()
{
    m_mouse->showCursor(true);
    if (m_glContext)
    {
        glXMakeCurrent(m_display, None, NULL);
        glXDestroyContext(m_display, m_glContext);
        m_glContext = NULL;
    }

    if (m_isFullscreen)
    {
        XF86VidModeSwitchToMode(m_display, m_screenID, &m_XF86DeskMode);
        XF86VidModeSetViewPort(m_display, m_screenID, 0, 0);
    }
    XDestroyWindow(m_display, m_XWindow);
    XCloseDisplay(m_display);
}


void SimpleGLXWindow::setWindowTitle(char* wName)
{
    m_windowTitle = wName;
}

void SimpleGLXWindow::swapBuffers() { glXSwapBuffers(m_display, m_XWindow); }

void SimpleGLXWindow::processEvents()
{

    m_keyboard->update();
    m_mouse->update();

    XEvent event;
    while (XPending(m_display))
    {
        XNextEvent(m_display, &event);
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case Expose:
            {
                if (event.xexpose.count != 0)
                    break;

                break;
            }

            case ConfigureNotify:
            {
                windowWidth = event.xconfigure.width;
                windowHeight = event.xconfigure.height;
                getAttachedExample()->onResize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
            }
            case MotionNotify:
            {
                //on mouse move
                m_mouse->changeMouseMoveState();
                break;
            }

            case ButtonRelease:
            {
            //Eventos del Mouse
                switch (event.xbutton.button)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        //click izquierdo
    //                    t_prev=t_new;
    //                    printf("Click Occured      : [%d, %d]\n",
    //                           xevent.xbutton.x_root,
    //                           xevent.xbutton.y_root);
                        m_mouse->changeMouseButtonState(0,false);
                        break;
                    }

                    case 2:
                    {
                        //click central
                        m_mouse->changeMouseButtonState(2,false);
                        break;
                    }

                    case 3:
                    {
                        //click derecho
                        m_mouse->changeMouseButtonState(1,false);
                        break;
                    }

                    case 4:
                    {
                        //scroll up
                        break;
                    }

                    case 5:
                    {
                        //scroll down
                        break;
                    }
                    //en el default entra si no se toco ningún botón, por lo tanto hace que todos
                    //vuelvan al estado false.
                    default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;

            }

            case ButtonPress:
            {
                //Eventos del Mouse
                switch (event.xbutton.button)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        //click izquierdo
    //                    t_prev=t_new;
    //                    printf("Click Occured      : [%d, %d]\n",
    //                           xevent.xbutton.x_root,
    //                           xevent.xbutton.y_root);
                        m_mouse->changeMouseButtonState(0,true);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2:
                    {
                        //click central
                        m_mouse->changeMouseButtonState(2,true);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3:
                    {
                        //click derecho
                        m_mouse->changeMouseButtonState(1,true);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 4:
                    {
                        //scroll up
                        break;
                    }
                    case 5:
                    {
                        //scroll down
                        break;
                    }
                    //en el default entra si no se toco ningún botón, por lo tanto hace que todos
                    //vuelvan al estado false.
                    default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }



            case KeyPress:
            {
                if (XLookupKeysym(&event.xkey,0) == XK_Escape) {
                    m_isRunning = false;
                }

                //Register the key press with the keyboard interface
                m_keyboard->handleKeyDown(m_keyboard->translateKey(XLookupKeysym(&event.xkey,0)));
                break;
            }

            case KeyRelease:
            {
                BOGLGPKeyCode code = m_keyboard->translateKey(XLookupKeysym(&event.xkey,0));
                m_keyboard->handleKeyUp(code);
                break;
            }

            case ClientMessage:
            {
//                if (string(XGetAtomName(m_display, event.xclient.message_type)) == string("WM_PROTOCOLS"))
//                {
//                    m_isRunning = false;
//                }

                if((static_cast<unsigned int>(event.xclient.data.l[0]) == WM_DELETE_WINDOW))
                {
                    m_isRunning = false;
                }
                break;
            }


            default:
            {
                break;
            }

        }

    }

}

bool SimpleGLXWindow::isRunning()
{
    return m_isRunning;
}

void SimpleGLXWindow::attachExample(SGE3D::core* example)
{
    m_example = example;
}


float SimpleGLXWindow::getElapsedSeconds()
{
    unsigned int currentTime = GetTickCount();
    unsigned int diff = currentTime - m_lastTime;
    m_lastTime = currentTime;
    return float(diff) / 1000.0f;
}
}
#endif //WIN32
```

when i call the SimpleGLXWindow::create() function, i get this error (between my debug messages):

```
iniciando ventana linux
Found 2 matching FB configs.
Getting XVisualInfos
Matching fbconfig 0, visual ID 163: SAMPLE_BUFFERS = 1, SAMPLES = 4
Matching fbconfig 1, visual ID 164: SAMPLE_BUFFERS = 1, SAMPLES = 8
Chosen visual ID = 164
Creating colormap
Creating window
Mapping window
Creating context
Failed to create GL 3.3 context ... using old-style GLX context
Direct GLX rendering context obtained
Making context current
X Error of failed request:  BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (DRI2)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (DRI2CreateDrawable)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x4200002
  Serial number of failed request:  40
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

i work with CodeBlocks IDE and my linked libraries are:

```
-L libs -Wl,-rpath libs
-Wl,-Bstatic
/home/fabian/Proyectos/SGE3D/libs/SOIL/lib/libSOIL.a
/home/fabian/libreriasDeDesarrollo/minGW/lib/libglu32.a
/home/fabian/libreriasDeDesarrollo/minGW/lib/libfreeglut.a
-Wl,-Bdynamic
libs/libGlew-1-10-sge3d.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so
libs/libfreetype-6-11-1-sge3d.so
libs/libfreeimage-3-sge3d.so
libs/libassimp-3-sge3d.so
```

The -sge3d.so are the system libraries (/usr/lib/) copy/pasted with different name to avoid that the user needs to install it (this work fine in 32 bits).

i look the ldd output and this looks right:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3f3ad000)
    libGLEW.so.1.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.10 (0x00007f70b6530000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f70b61f7000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f70b5f5a000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f70b5d54000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f70b5aac000)
    libfreeimage.so.3 => /usr/lib/libfreeimage.so.3 (0x00007f70b5803000)
    libassimp.so.3 => /usr/lib/libassimp.so.3 (0x00007f70b4f8d000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f70b4c7e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f70b4977000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f70b4760000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f70b439c000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f70b417c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f70b3f78000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f70b3d4f000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f70b3b22000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f70b3910000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f70b370d000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f70b3506000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f70b3304000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f70b30ed000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f70b2ee7000)
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f70b2ce4000)
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f70b2ae1000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f70b28da000)
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f70b26d8000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f70b24cb000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f70b22ac000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f70b2093000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f70b1e6c000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f70b1c17000)
    libopenjpeg.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjpeg.so.5 (0x00007f70b19f4000)
    libIlmImf.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so.6 (0x00007f70b1744000)
    libHalf.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so.6 (0x00007f70b1501000)
    libIex.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so.6 (0x00007f70b12e3000)
    libraw.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libraw.so.10 (0x00007f70b103d000)
    libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f70b0dc9000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f70b67d7000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f70b0bc4000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f70b09be000)
    libIlmThread.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so.6 (0x00007f70b07b6000)
    libjasper.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so.1 (0x00007f70b055f000)
    liblcms2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms2.so.2 (0x00007f70b0308000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f70b00f1000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f70afecf000)
    libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007f70afcc1000)
```

but... i don't see my "sge3d" libraries linked in.

This is the glxinfo report (it seems that everything it's ok):

```
fabian@fabian-ThinkPad-L440:~$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-ba35393 2015-04-04 utopic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-ba35393 2015-04-04 utopic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-ba35393 2015-04-04 utopic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until [no code can be removed while still running into the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What is `glxinfo` reporting on that system? There might be just an issue with the GL drivers.

Comment: i added the glxinfo in the post. thanks

Comment: There is no way anyone can reproduce this.

Answer (score 2):

You are requesting a 3.3 *compatibility* profile here:

```
int context_attribs[] =
  {
    GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
    GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
    GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB , GLX_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
    //GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB        , GLX_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
    None
  };
```

[Mesa does not support the compatibility profile:](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/plain/docs/GL3.txt)

> OpenGL Core and Compatibility context support
>
> OpenGL 3.1 and later versions are only supported with the Core
>   profile. There are no plans to support GL_ARB_compatibility. The last
>   supported OpenGL version with all deprecated features is 3.0. Some of
>   the later GL features are exposed in the 3.0 context as extensions.

(note that OpenGL 3.1 core profile doesn't even exist, Mesa made that one up. Profiles were introduced in GL 3.2).

And this is exactly what `glxinfo` is telling you:

```
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-ba35393 2015-04-04 utopic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-ba35393 2015-04-04 utopic-oibaf-ppa)
```

Comment: thanks derhass! but this doesn't solve the problem :(  i changed this in the code:

int context_attribs[] =
  {
    GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
    GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
    None
  };

Comment: and the problem continues with the same error messages that i indicated in the post, "cant create a Opengl 3.3 context" (this code in 32 bits work fine). i dont understand why :(

Comment: Well, just removing the compat profile request won't wotk. You have to explicitely request a core profile.

Comment: thanks again, but i dont see which the changes are that i need realize in the window code to create a simple 3.3 OpenGL context, can you help me? i dont found the solution in google (Maybe I've looked the wrong way).

Comment: You'll definitively need the `GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB , GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB` attribute when requesting the context.

Comment: thanks, but this not solve my problem...

Comment: only works in 32 bits (the same code),  but not in 64 :(